# C# ASP.Net - DataList Changing Images On The Fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, datalist

I have a simple DataList that is getting text data from one field in a database and displaying it horizontally in the lblProductName label.  This works great.  In my database I have 4 records and it displays 1 row with 4 columns of data in a table in the DataList.  Perfect.

The harder part.  Based on another query/logic I want to display an image under the lblProductName label in the DataList; either a switchon.jpg or a switchoff.jpg.  This I have no idea how to do since I'm binding the DataList with the original query to the database.

Here is my Datalist.

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlstProductDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns = "5" CellPadding = "10" HorizontalAlign ="Center" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="100%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="ProductLinks">
                <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' /><br />
                <asp:Image ID="imgProductStatus" runat="server"></asp:Image>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Here is my code to load the data into the DataList.

```
    var cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TaktBoardsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    string sql = "SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName] FROM [Product] WHERE [ProductID] <> 1 ORDER BY [ProductID]";
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.Connection.Open();
    dlstProductDataList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dlstProductDataList.DataBind();

    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
```

The code/logic to get the image would look something like this...

Somehow for each lblProductName that gets bound in the DataList I would have to execute the following query.  If the query below returns 0 in ProductCount then I'd set the imgProductStatus to be switchoff.jpg.  If it's > 0 then it would be set to switchon.jpg.  For each lblProductName I know the ProductID (as per the first query above).

```
    sql = "SELECT COUNT([ProductID]) AS ProductCount FROM TaktBoard WHERE [ProductID] = ??????? AND CONVERT (date, [BoardDate]) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())";
```

If anyone can steer me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!!

Andy

Comment: Hi Kirk, unfortunately the way the database is set up there is another table TaktBoard that I have to check to see if there are any saved records that have a productID for the product name I'm searching for.  So I have to do a secondary query to check for that.

Comment: It is better to create a query with all the information you need. Therefore , create a query with a subquery (or the use of binding ) to take all the data you need . Then change the template elements. To summarize: bring all the data you need on the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your query to include the count.

You'll need to include this in your SQL too, there are a few ways to do this such as with a join, but without seeing your full schema, you may have more luck with a subquery

```
string sql = "SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], (select COUNT([ProductID]) FROM TaktBoard tb WHERE tb.[ProductID] = [Product].[ProductID] AND CONVERT (date, [BoardDate]) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())) as [ProductCount] FROM [Product] WHERE [ProductID] <> 1 ORDER BY [ProductID]";
```

Formatted a bit more to see

```
SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName],
(
    select COUNT([ProductID])
    FROM TaktBoard tb
    WHERE tb.[ProductID] = [Product].[ProductID]
    AND CONVERT (date, [BoardDate]) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE())
) as [ProductCount]

FROM [Product]
WHERE [ProductID] <> 1 
ORDER BY [ProductID]
```

Then use this within your image.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgProductStatus" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ProductCount")) == 0) ? "~/Images/switchoff.jpg" : "~/Images/switchon.jpg" %>'></asp:Image>
```

Comment: This will be awesome if it works.  I added the '%>' and the image looks like this now.


    `<asp:Image ID="imgProductStatus" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ProductCount")) = 0) ? "Images/switchoff.jpg" : "Images/switchon.jpg"%>'></asp:Image>`


... and I get the errors

Comment: I've updated the code for the image, might try `~Images` if it's from your application root

Comment: It works!!!  Kirk, thank you. There's no way I could have figured this out on my own.  You're a rockstar.  Sorry.. the errors were before you updated the image code.